# Angular Validator fire on component load

Tags: angular

i have custom angular validator defined as below

```
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ecMinVal]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: ecMinVal,
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class ecMinVal implements Validator {
  @Input() ecMinVal = 0;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    return Number(control.value) < this.ecMinVal ? { 'lessThanMinVal': true } : null;
  }
}
```

I am using it in number textbox component like this

```
<div class="input-container inline">
  <input type="number"
         #txtBoxNumber="ngModel"
         [ecMinVal]="ecMinVal1"
         [(ngModel)]="value"
         (focus)="onFocus($event)"
         (ngModelChange)="change($event)"
         onkeydown="if(event.key==='.' || event.key==='e' || event.key==='E'){event.preventDefault();}"
         ng-required="required">


  <div *ngIf="txtBoxNumber.errors?.['lessThanMinVal'] " class="row alert alert-danger alert-div">
    <span>
      Value should be greater than or equal to {{ecMinVal1}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want user to see the validation *Value should be greater than or equal to {{ecMinVal1}}* . This works fine when user changes value and the value is less than the value of variable *ecMinVal1*

However i want user to see this message when component finished loading in their browser and even if the user has not changed anything.

Not sure why the **txtBoxNumber.errors** is null on component load and is populated when user changes value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because by default value is null and in validator you are converting the value

1. Number(null) which yields 0,  0 < 0 is false
2. Number(undefined) which yields NaN, NaN < 0 is false.

You can add some check before

```
    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const value = control.value;
    if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value === null) {
      return { lessThanMinVal: true };
    }
    return Number(value) < this.ecMinVal ? { lessThanMinVal: true } : null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Indraraj26. You are absolutely correct!